# How can i set queuename in rebus azure queue oneway client

Tags: c#, rebus, azure-queues

I have a rebus- worker that runs on azure queue, I have configured the rebusworker that will receive and send messages and it works fine. But then I want to set up a client as a oneway client like this:

```
   _bus = Configure.With(adapter)                
                .Transport(
                t =>
                    t.UseAzureStorageQueuesAsOneWayClient(AppSettingsReader.AzureStorage)
                )

            .Routing(r => r.TypeBased()
                .MapAssemblyOf<SomeCommand>(queueAddress)
            )

            })
            .Start();
    }
```

Where can i set the queue name I want to send messages to? As is it returns a null-reference exception for queuename.

I'm using rebus and rebus.AzureStorage 0.99.74

Answer (score 0):

The `queueAddress` in your snippet should be name of the queue, to which you would like to send messages from the assembly of `SomeCommand`.

To be very concrete, let's pretend you

```
.Routing(r => r.TypeBased()
    .MapAssemblyOf<SomeCommand>("commandprocessor")
)
```

and then you

```
await bus.Send(new SomeCommand(...));
```

then Rebus will send that message to the queue `commandprocessor`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, as a temporarily workaround I have done it like this to make it work. Because the oneway client cast an exception I configured it as a regular client with a dummy queue address in the transport settings. And I added the queuename I want to use in Routing..  .Transport(
                    t =>
                        t.UseAzureStorageQueues(AppSettingsReader.AzureStorage,"dummyqueue")
                    )

                .Routing(r => r.TypeBased()
                    .MapAssemblyOf<SomeCommand>("NameofTheQueueToSendTo")
                )